# How to parse and output JSON object with dynamic values?

Tags: java, jquery, json, parsing

i am creating a web app. in which i need to parse a json which is having dynamic values.

```
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    int  i=0;
        while(rs.next())
        {
            i++;
            object.put("qno"+i,rs.getInt(1));
            object.put("qname"+i,rs.getString(2));
            object.put("opA"+i,rs.getString(3));
            object.put("opB"+i,rs.getString(4));
            object.put("opC"+i,rs.getString(5));
            object.put("opD"+i,rs.getString(6));
            object.put("answer"+i,rs.getString(7));
        }
```

i am getting JSON like this...     `{"qno1":"1","qname":"asdgdfh","qno2":"2" ........ .... ....  "qno20":"20"......}`

how can i get the values by parsing the json using jQuery.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name1":"John","name2":"Mary"}');
alert( obj.name1 === "John" );
```

with foreach-loop:

```
for (var o in obj) {
    alert(o + " " + obj[o]);
}
```

Comment: i have json like this     {"name1":"john","name2":"adil","name3":"vikas"......}   and i want to access these values inside a loop  without having to write this    obj.name1  or obj.name2  explicitly...

Comment: If you want use loop check my example - I've just added it

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want dynamic object names? Seems like that would make all the code you use to deal with it more complicated. Doable, by why not just pass the number you're adding to the object name as value, and use an array of objects. E.g. create objects that look like this

```
{ "qno": 
    [{"id":1,"value":"somedata"},
     {"id":2,"value":"somedata"},
     ...],
  "qname": ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this has to be completely dynamic...

```
 json = {"a1" : "one", "a2" : "two"}

 for (var key in json){
    // key = key
    // value = json[key]
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what more detail you need.  What are you trying to do with these values?